# Centering layout in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

If I use the following structure in the `Scaffold`:

```
  body: Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child:
        Text('Test')  
  )
```

Then the text is vertically and centrally structured, as I want. But if I do the following:

```
body: Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child:
        ListView(
          children:people.map(person).toList(),
        ),

  )
```

Then the ListView is stuck to the top left of the body and isn't centered.

Why is that, and how can I center the ListView the same way that Text was centered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vertical

```
body: Container(
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  child:
    ListView(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      children:people.map(person).toList(),
    ),
 )
```

Horizontal

```
ListView(
    shrinkWrap: true,
    children: [
      Row(
         mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
         children: [
            Text('text'),
         ],
       ),
       Text('text'),
       Text('text'),
     ],
   ),
```

[image]

Comment: What about horizontal centering?

Comment: I think you'll have to do that inside the individual list items, I'll update my response

Answer (score 1):

It's because ListView take all the space available. To tell Listview to take only children sizes, add property "shrinkWrap" to true.

```
Center(
  child: ListView(
    shrinkWrap: true,
    children: <Widget>[
      Center(
        child: Text("Hello world !"),
      ),
    ],
  ),
)
```

Comment: That works for vertical centering, what if I also want to horizontally center the list?

Comment: You can add an extra Center widget around each child I think. I tested on Flutter pad, it works, i edited my answer :).

Comment: Thanks for your help